# Proving that if $C$ is a compact set $|p-q|=diam(C)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Okay So prove of this is done in this way :

Choose sequences ${p_n}$ and ${q_n}$ in $C$ with $lim|p_n − q_n| = diam(C)$. Since $S$ is compact,
$p_n$ has a subsequence $p_{nk}$ that converges to some point $p ∈ C$. Since
$|p_{nk}−q_{nk}|≤|p_{nk} −p|+|p−q_{nk}|≤|p_{nk} −p|+diam(C)$,
letting $k → ∞$ we obtain $diam(C) ≤ lim|p − q_{nk} | ≤ diam(C)$ so that $lim |p − q_{nk} | = diam(C)$. Using again the compactness of $S$, we conclude that the sequence ${r_k}$ given by $r_k = q_{nk}$ has a subsequence $r_{kl}$ converging to a point $q ∈ C$ so that
$|p−q|= lim |p−r_{kl}|= lim |p−q_{nk}|=diam(C)$

**I couldn't understand the role of subsequences here. Could someone make it clear for me? Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of supremum, we can write the diameter as a limit of distances between points $p_n$ and $q_n$. But there is no reason a priori for which the sequence $\left(p_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges. For example, in the case where $C$ is the closed unit interval, we could choice $p_n=1/n$, $q_n=1-1/n$ for $n$ even and  $p_n=1-1/n$, $q_n=1/n$ for $n$ odd. But we are sure that a subsequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to invoke subsequences here. If $(E,d)$ is a metric space with $C\subset E$ compact, then for each $x\in C$, the map $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous and therefore attains a maximum at some $y_x\in C$. By the same logic, the map $x\mapsto d(x,y_x)$ is continuous and attains a maximum at some $p\in C$. Let $q:= y_p$. Then 
$$\operatorname{diam} C = \sup_{x,y\ \in\  C}d(x,y) = d(p,q).  $$